# Training error of a svm using scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

I would like to calculate the training error (mean square error of the fit performed with respect to the training set) and the cross validation error of my cross validation set. How is that possible using SVC or linearSVC in sklearn?

Comment: Usually the zero-one error is used for classification, not MSE. Why do you want MSE?
For obtaining the classification score,look in the docs ;)

Comment: Are you doing regression or classification? MSE or RMSE is used for regression...

Comment: You are right. I am doing classification and I was attempting to use MeanSquaredError, however it won't work well, it's right to use the miscassification error... thank you